# What's the difference between the Minkowski difference of $A$ and $B$ and the Minkowski sum of $A$ and $-B$?

Tags: geometry, polygons, sumset

In the book *Computational Geometry*, Algorithms and Applications from de Berg, van Kreveld, Overmars and schwarzkopf, I read the following in chapter 13.3 on Minkowski sums:

> Sometimes $ P \oplus(-R(0,0))$ is referred to as the *Minkowski difference* of $P$ and $R(0,0)$. Since **Minkowski differences are defined differently in the mathematics literature** we shall avoid this.

Both $P$ and $R(0,0)$ are polygons, that is: a set of points in $\mathbb R^2$.

Beforehand, the following definitions are made:

For two sets $S_{1,2} \subset \mathbb R^2$, the Minkowski sum is defined as:

$$S_1 \oplus S_2 := \{p+q:p\in S_1, q \in S_2\}$$

For the vectors $p=(p_x,p_y)$ and $q=(q_x,q_y)$, the sum is defined as

$$p+q := (p_x+q_x,p_y+q_y)$$

For a point $p=(p_x,p_y)$, it's defined that

$$-p := (-p_x, -p_y)$$

and for a set $S$ it is defined that

$$-S := \{-p : p \in S\}$$

**If not by $A \oplus -B$, how *else* is a Minkowski difference  of the two sets defined?** In what cases is that difference important?

Answer (score 3):

This is late but maybe helpful, check out the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition).
Basically the idea is that (A - B ) + B = A, so we define

$$A - B = \{ c \in V | c + B \subseteq A \} $$